# Riemann (darboux?) integrating $f: [2,3] \to \mathbb{R} \quad f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I have function $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} $$
I want to riemann *(I don't know whether what I mean is actually Riemann or Darboux integration)* integrate it on the interval $$ x \in \left[2,3\right] $$

What I could do is partition the interval into subintervals, first stating that
$$ 2 = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n =3 \implies P=(x_0, \: \dots \:, x_n)$$

And

$$ m_i = \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1}-x_{i}]}{\left( f(x) \right)} $$
$$ M_i = \sup_{x \in [x_{i-1}-x_{i}]}{\left( f(x) \right)} $$

So I can tell the darboux (??) sums:

Lower: $L_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-x_{i-1})m_i}$

Upper: $U_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-x_{i-1})M_i}$

I could find $m_i$ and then, for example, $L_{f,P}$ is:

$$L_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-x_{i-1}) \left( \frac{1}{x_i^2} \right)}$$

**How do I continue?**

I know that I should find what this value approaches as $n \to \infty$ and check whether $U_{f,P}$ approaches the same number to find the integral. But I can't take limits of sums and I don't know how I should simplify that...

**Please, if possible, I'd like simple and beginner-level answers**

Comment: You didn't actually specify your partition.  How do you want to partition the interval?  The easiest would probably be $x_i =  2+ \frac{3-2}{n}i = 2+\frac in$.

Comment: What if I don't want equal length subintervals? I mean I want to solve it in such a way that  subintervals are of arbitrary length. (I might be talking nonsense, in that case, sorry...)

Comment: I plugged in the {x_i} you gave and got this... 
$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ \left( \left( 2 + \frac{i}{n} \right) - \left( 2 + \frac{i-1}{n}   \right) \right) \left( \frac{1}{ { \left( 2 + \frac{i}{n} \right) }^2 } \right) } = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{4+ \frac{4i}{n}+{i^2{{n^2}}}} } = n \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{4n^2+4in+i^2}} $

Comment: $$ = n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(2n+i)^2} = n\sum_{k=2n+1}^{3n}\frac 1{k^2}$$  Now take the limit (actually the last step might make it harder, so you could just use the second to last one).

Comment: @Bye_World I haven't really learned about sums, may I ask what rule you used to do this step? Secondly, is there a way to even calculate this? Isn't the answer a harmonic number? Can I 'evaluate' that?

Comment: I just did a change of variables $k=2n+i$.  And this isn't harmonic -- it's a polygamma function.  Which is a bit of a problem... hmm.

Comment: Use the subdivision $x_k=2q^k$, $q^N=\frac32$, then the summation reduces to geometric sums.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I \subset\mathbb{R}$ be a closed interval and $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{L}f := \sup_{P \text{ is a partition of }I}L_{f,P}\\
\mathrm{U}f := \inf_{P \text{ is a partition of }I}U_{f,P}.
\end{eqnarray}
and $|P| > 0$ be the maximum length among the subinterevals in $P$, where $P$ is a partiton of $I$.

Then there is a theorem that

*for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t. if a
partition $P$ of $I$ satisfies $|P| < \delta$ then \begin{eqnarray}
\left| L_{f,P}-Lf \right| < \varepsilon\\ \left| U_{f,P}-Uf \right| <
\varepsilon. \end{eqnarray}*

Hence you can calculate the lower and upper Riemannian integral with partitions whose subintervals are of length $\frac{1}{n}$.

In order to calculate the lower one, calculate
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\left( 2 + \frac{i}{n} \right)\left( 2 + \frac{i-1}{n} \right)}
\end{eqnarray}
instead of
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\left( 2 + \frac{i}{n} \right)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
and then estimate the difference to each other.